# Question(s) about time complexity of array "resizing" in Java

Tags: java, arrays, memory, time-complexity

**NOTE:** As the title already hints, this question is **not** about the specific `java.util.ArrayList` implementation of an array-based list, but rather about the raw arrays themselves and how they might behave in a "pure" (meaning completely unoptimized) array-based list implementation. I chose to mention `java.util.ArrayList` because it is the most prominent example of an array-based list in Java, although it is technically not "pure", as it utilizes preallocation to reduce the operation time of `add()`. If you want to know why I am asking this specific question without being interested in the `java.util.ArrayList()` preallocation optimization, I added a little explanation of my use case below.

It is generally known that you can access elements in array-based lists (like Java's `ArrayList<E>`) with a time complexity of `O(1)`, while adding elements to that list will take `O(n)`. With linked lists, it is the other way round (for a doubly linked list, you could optimize the access to half the execution time).

The reason why adding elements to an array-based list takes `O(n)` is that an array cannot simply be resized, but has to be reallocated and re-filled. The easiest way to do this would be:

```
String arr[] = new String[n];
//...
String newElem = "foo";
String[] newArr = new String[n + 1];
int i = 0;
for (String elem : arr) {
    newArr[i] = arr[i++];
}
newArr[i] = newElem;
arr = newArr;
```

The time complexity `O(n)` is clearly visible thanks to the for loop. But there are other ways to copy arrays in Java, for example `System.arraycopy()`.

Sticking to the vanilla for loop solution, even *shrinking* an array will take `O(n)`, because an array has a fixed size and in order to "shrink" it, you'd have to copy all elements to be retained to a new, smaller array.

So, here are my questions concerning such array operations and their time complexity:

1. While the vanilla for loop will always take `O(n)`, is it possible that `System.arraycopy()` optimizes the "add" operation if there is enough space in the memory to expand the array in place, meaning that it would leave the original array at its place and just add the new element at the end of it?
2. As the shrinking operation could *always* be executed with `O(1)` in theory, does `System.arraycopy()` always optimize this operation to `O(1)`?
3. If `System.arraycopy()` is *not* capable of using those optimizations, is there any other way in Java to actually utilize those optimizations which are possible in theory *OR* will array "resizing" always take `O(n)`, no matter under which circumstances?

TL;DR is there any situation in which the "resizing" of an array in Java will take less than `O(n)`?

Additional information:

I am using openJDK11 (newest release), but if the answer turns out to be JVM-dependent, I'd like to know how other JVMs would behave in comparison.

## For the curious ones

who want to know what I want to do with this information:

I am working on a new `java.util.List` implementation, namely a hybrid list that can store data in an array *and* in a linked buffer. On certain occasions, the buffer will be flushed into the array, which of course requires that the existing array is resized. But apart from this idea, I want to utilize as many other optimizations on the array part as possible. To avoid array resizing in general, I experimented with the idea of letting the array persist in a constant size, but managing the "valid" range of it with some other fields. Meaning that if you were to pop the last element of the array, it would not shrink the array but rather the range of valid elements. Then, when inserting new elements in the array part, the former invalid section can be used to shift values into, basically reusing the space that was formerly used by a now deleted element. If the inserting operations exceed the actual array size, elements can still be transferred to the linked buffer to avoid resizing. To further optimize this, I chose to use the middle of the array as a pivot when deleting certain elements. Now the valid range might not start at the beginning of the array anymore. Basically this means if you delete an element to the left of the pivot, all elements between the start of the valid range and the deleted element get shifted towards the pivot, to the right. Removing element to the right of the pivot works accordingly. So, after some removals, the array could look like this:

```
[null null|elem0 elem1 elem2||elem3 elem4 elem5|null null null]
```

(Where the | at the beginning and at the end mark the valid range and the || marks the pivot)

So, how is this all related to my question?

All of those optimizations build up upon the claim that array resizing is expensive in time, namely `O(n)`. Therefore array resizing is avoided whenever possible. Those optimizations might sound neat, but the code implementing them can get quite messy, *especially* when implementing the batch operations (`addAll()`, `removeAll()`, `retainAll()`...). So, if it turns out that the array resizing operation itself can be less expensive in some cases (especially shrinking), I would cut out a lot of those optimizations which are then rendered useless, making the code a *lot* easier in the process.

So, before sticking to my optimization ideas and experiments, I'd like to know whether they are even needed.

Comment: These questions seem *very* JVM-vendor specific. The least one can say is that the Javadoc (even as of SE 14) makes no mention of this.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I am using openjdk 11 but I will add this information to my question

Comment: `System.arraycopy` leaves the original array in working order, so it can't be implemented in O(1) unless you used weird memory-mapping techniques that would certainly produce unexpected performance results. Also: "O(n)" and "O(n/2)" are equivalent.

Comment: @JoachimSauer That's what I thought about ```System.arraycopy()```, that answers questions 1 and 2, but what about 3? And about the ```O(n / 2)``` problem: I know, ```O(n)``` just states that the execution time will be linearly proportional to the input size, without saying anything about the proportion factor. I wanted to express the fact that a doubly linked list can perform access requests in half the time in comparison to a singly linked list, but I admit I chose the wrong notation. Will change.

Comment: "*while adding elements to that list will take O(n)*" - not all the time. ArrayList for example creates the internal array bit bigger than needed. And if it grows the array, it also grows it more than what is needed, to minimize the need to resize the array (I think the bigger the array gets, the bigger the proportional "over allocation" will be). So not **every** add operation is O(n) - only some.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Of course this is the case for that specific java ArrayList implementation. But the question is whether the array resizing _in general_ can take less than ```O(n)```. I need to know these informations to implement a hybrid list which uses an array and a linked buffer and should also utilize all other possible optimizations

Comment: This is easily done by pre-allocating when the array exceeds a certain length. Similar to the way it is done when a hash table is being increased when balance factor exceeds the threshold.

Comment: @amit amortized constant time means an average over a lot of operations, while I talk about a single ```add()```. As I explained in another comment, I know that ArrayList uses a preallocation optimization, but allocates more memory than needed as a trade-off. But my question is about resizing on arrays themselves or on the concept of array-based lists, supposing they don't utilize any optimizations in their purest form.

Comment: @Raphael You're thinking waayyy too low level about time complexity. Time complexity describes an algorithm not any specific implementation thereof. Copying an array conceptually requires to copy all existing elements to the new array. 
Also your optimizations are mostly exactly what ArrayList is doing anyhow.

Comment: It should also be noted that LinkedLists are one of the worst data structure on modern CPUs due to their  cache behavior and that there are very, very few situattions where they're better than ArrayLists. No seriously for most situations it's faster to add to the middle of an ArrayList than a LinkedList. Thinking about time complexity when optimizing existing code can be helpful but there's much more to it than that - if you don't have benchmarks that's the first thing to do. (I also don't understand why you'd care about worst case and not amortized performance for your use case).

Comment: @Voo I did not ask for your personal opinion on linked lists in comparison to arraylists or on my personal implementation of a buffered arraylist. Also, I did not ask about the time complexity of array _copyiing_ (which is of course always ```O(n)```), but rather of resizing the allocated memory range of an array. Furthermore, time complexity only describes the proportion of the input size to the execution time of an algorithm. It is applicable to concrete implementations as well as abstract concepts, as you can always abstract a specific case to a concept

Comment: @Raphael Linked lists being awful is not personal opinion, but easily measurable (and explainable by their cache behavior and how modern CPUs work). The thing about time complexity is that it abstracts constants away that do matter in reality. QuickSort is faster than MergeSort in practical applications, despite being O(n^2) vs. O(n log n). There are matrix mulitplications that have faster Big O numbers than Strassen, but require more elements than atoms in the universe and so on. That's why Big O is only of limited use when trying to improve performance in real systems.

Comment: But it's just advice that you're worrying about the wrong thing and should write benchmarks (preferably using [jmh](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)) at which point you don't have to guess anymore but have hard numbers to work with. If you're not worried about actual performance, but theoretical concepts then just ignore it.

Comment: @Voo Okay, look, this is nothing personal. I really appreciate that you care about my implementation and how I could improve it. But my question is stated clear and all I want is a precise answer to it. Arguing about the best list type or how to interpret big O notation doesn't actually help me with that question. Please don't take this as a personal insult or something, I'm just trying to get helpful tips and answers to my three questions. I am still thankful for the side informations you gave me and I'll find a way to use them in my code

Comment: No offense taken. Anyhow, array sizes are immutable in HotSpot from what I know. There is a set_length in `src/share/vm/oops/arrayOop.hpp` so it would theoretically be possible, but it seems to be only used during allocation. It would also be rarely useful, since the heap is reasonably compacted by GC so you shouldn't have lots of free space between different objects.

Comment: @Voo Thanks, this really helps me! Do you happen to know whether the same applies to "shrinking" an array, as in deleting an element and trying to make the array smaller? Anyway, if you want to, you can post this as an answer, I would accept it.

Comment: @Raphael That could be made to work (make the object smaller and the next time the heap is compacted it uses less space), but given the complications and the very rare use case I don't see any indication that anyone ever made the effort. This would be somewhat different if it was on the large object heap, but that's even more of a niche use case and as long as you weren't using the old memory it could just get paged out without troubles, so not much reason to worry about it. Virtual address space is cheap these days.